# Do we ever pronounce "g" in "ing" - example "going out"

Tags: pronunciation

OK, I know that I will never pronounce "g" in "ing".

But what should I do in situations like "going out"?

When I say it, it seems that I pronounced "g". There are other situations like this but this one happens more often than others.

Comment: Why will you never pronounce "g" in -ing?

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/ing

Comment: It's not that I completely omit it, but I do not say "g" clearly as in the work "gap"

Comment: AmE here.  The degree to which the "g" is pronounced depends on the context, the speed of speech, the accent of the speaker, the particular word being pronounced, and the word that follows.  I doubt there are many speakers who _never_ pronounce it; nor are there many speakers who _always_ pronounce it.  Imagine your phrase said with disbelief: "You're doing _what?_  You're **going out??"**  <--Here I pronounce the "g" very clearly.  VS: "I'm going out to the store - do you want me to pick anything up for you?"  <--  Here the "going out" is not emphasized, and will sound like "go-wi-nout."

Comment: @Adam You're saying that emphasis on "g" in "going out" means my anger? Like father talking to a daughter? While in casual speech, you can omit it.

Comment: It doesn't mean anger necesarily.   Could be disbelief, excitement, anger, confusion, clarification, sorrow - any reason that makes you want to stress the concept of "going out._".  It's just emphasis.  If you think that the important part of the entire utterance is the "going out" part, then you might stress those words more, and slow them down.  If you do that, you are likely to inject more "g" sound - but maybe you won't.  This is a very flexible point of pronunciation.

Comment: Other note - when I say that you might pronounce the _g_, I mean that you might say it as the people in your two examples do.  I hear a _g_ in both of those sound clips.  Dropping the _g_ would shift  the vowel sound to a short i, and firmly close off the sound with an n. "**Go**win"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement that you 'never pronounce "g" in "-ing" refers to the **sound** /g/. The **spelling** ‹ng› almost never<sup>†</sup> involves the **sound** /g/. ‹ng› is a 'digraph' (like ‹th›)—in almost all cases it represents the sound /ŋ/, the consonant at the end of *sing*, *hang*, *long*.

So there is no actual /g/ sound in the *-ing* suffix. In speech, however, pronunciation alternates between "standard" /ŋ/ and a more casual /n/. This is  sometimes written with an apostrophe, *singin’, hangin’, goin’*, to emphasize that the pronunciation is casual or dialectal, and in non-technical discussion this is often called "dropping the g"—but it is "dropped" only from the spelling!

Either /ŋ/ or /n/ is acceptable in speech with the *-ing* suffix, and usually nobody will notice which you employ.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>The sound /ŋ/ **does** transition to /g/ in a few words such as *linger* (/lɪŋgər/) and *hunger* (/hʌŋgər/). The /g/ sound is obligatory in those words. To the best of my knowledge, however, this occurs only in the middle of words, never at the end. Some dialects expand this transition to situations where a word ending in /ŋ/ takes a suffix starting with a vowel; many New Yorkers for instance, pronounce *singing* as /sɪŋgiŋ/. But I've never encountered this across word boundaries.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It expanded my knowledge on "ing", but did not help much. I guess I could not get straight answer to this. The pronunciation of this is too vague I guess and depends on many unpredicted factors (like Adam mentioned).

Comment: @sandalone Does this rewrite help?

Comment: @sandalone Consider maybe the difference between "finger" and "singer," only in the first does *g* have a separate sound. We never say *finger* as we do *singer*. (Ah, okay, just now I see the small print in StoneyB's example of *linger*...)

Comment: English has a few of these combinations which arguably represent a distinct letter... e.g. "ng", "ch", sh". Indeed, other European languages often represent them as a single accented character - e.g. Spanish uses "ñ" where we would write "ny", and some of the eastern European languages use things like "č" and "š" rather than "ch" and "sh".