# What is it called when you replace the last letter of a word with an apostrophe?

Tags: word-request

I am analysing lyrics and talking about informal register.

I came across words like workin', and bangin', what is it called when you remove the last letter and replace it with an apostrophe (this letter seems to be silent)?

Comment: It's just ***standard writing / orthography*** - reflecting the fact that many people in many ***spoken*** contexts don't enunciate that final /g/ anyway. Not quite the same as [***eye dialect***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) - *the use of **deliberately nonstandard spelling** to emphasize how a word is being pronounced*.

Comment: But arguably the above is potentially misleading. Even though it's quite possible that *most* native Anglophones in *most* contexts don't enunciate that final /g/, we only normally transcribe it with the apostrophe when we want to call attention to it. Usually, the intention is to imply the speaker is stupid and/or poorly-educated (despite the fact that "well-educated" speakers routinely speak like this too).

Comment: ...but note that [*the huntin' and shootin' people*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+huntin+and+shootin+people%22) (or *set*) is idiomatically well-established orthography for "landed gentry, upper class, old money, royalty", etc. (wealthy well-educated people who stereotypically drop their /g/'s as a kind of "affectation" in such contexts).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call the act of removing a part of a word and replacing it with an apostrophe?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/200828/what-do-you-call-the-act-of-removing-a-part-of-a-word-and-replacing-it-with-an-a) See also [Do we ever pronounce "g" in "ing" - example "going out"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56130/do-we-ever-pronounce-g-in-ing-example-going-out)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - ...but note also that those Ngram results all seem to come from Orwell's _Road to Wigan Pier_ (1937). Dorothy Sayers has Lord Peter Wimsey talk like that in the 1920s-30s too, but I think the 'upper-class' usage is long since obsolete.

Comment: @KateBunting: Orwell didn't always have his finger on the pulse of conversational English! I wanted to link to *huntin' an' shootin' **set*** (the version I've heard and used hundreds of times over a lifetime), but Orwell's version was far more common (as you imply, because of reprints), so I just went with it. The "full" idiom is [*the huntin' shootin' **and fishin' set***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22huntin+shootin+and+fishin+set%22), which gets far more hits than Orwell's version anyway. Curiously, we never apostrophize ***and*** there (but it's almost *always* contracted).